# Unable to select data locally

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, local

Right, so when I run:

```
 Select * from Consultants
```

I get:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The table clearly exists in the object browser.

However, when I run:

```
 select * from Customers@xe.m512Finn
```

I get the data requested.

Please don't tell me that the table in the local database doesn't exist because it does; I created it and it's there in the object browser.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Please help me with any suggestions.

Comment: Probably the DBlink `xe.m512Finn` uses a different Oracle user (and thus schema) - and yes I am telling you that the table isn't there. You can trust Oracle with that error message!

Comment: What "object browser" are you using? Are you sure your browser is showing tables/views in the instance AND schema you're currently logged in as? What object type does your "object browser" say `Consultants` is?

Answer (score 4):

Here you're selecting from the `Consultants` table

```
Select * from Consultants
```

And here you're selecting from the `Customers` table

```
select * from Customers@xe.m512Finn
```

Comment: yes i know what's happening, but the issue is i'm getting no data from    the local Consultants table

Comment: So why don't you do a `select * from Consultants@xe.m512Finn`?

Answer (score 0):

The table does exists in m512Finn user that's why it returns the values for

```
select * from Customers@xe.m512Finn
```

You might be running that query in a different schema  or the query u might be looking for must be

```
Select * from consultants@xe.m512Finn
```

Comment: i am not looking for Select * from consultants@xe.m512Finn    because it's the local database tables i'm looking to query, not the remote database

Answer (score 0):

Okay  i've resolved the issue, it's that when you query local tables, you need double quotation marks around the table name.

select * from "Consultants"